# How to find if a bundle product is out of stock?

Tags: magento

I am setting a bundle product **out of stock** in inventory (Stock Availability option) in magento admin.

Still I am getting message as inn stock for that bundle product on product detail page.

In `app\design\frontend\default\rfg\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle.phtml`

we have following code

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>         
    <p class="availability in-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>           
<?php endif; ?>
```

Why this code does not work for the bundle product?

I want to show out of stock message if the product is itself not in stock(It should not be dependent on bundle items )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>         
    <p class="availability in-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>           
<?php endif; ?>
```

by

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>         
    <p class="availability in-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>           
<?php endif; ?>
```

And reindex all

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Manage Product Page and select your product and then go to the inventory and set qty as "0" (Zero) then clears catch and indexes.

i hope this answer is working for you.